# How to create a brush with pygame?

Tags: pygame

I'm trying to create a brush on pygame. It should draw rectangles while the left mouse button is down.

Below is what I tried:

```
while not game_exit:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            while pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1], 10, 10])
```

But it is now working. Where is the problem?

Comment: where is `pygame.display.flip()` or `pygame.display.update()`?

Comment: where is `pygame.event.get()`?

Comment: you can use `event.button == 1` with `event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to draw rectangle when mouse button is pressed (and mouse is moving) then use

```
import pygame

RED = (255,0,0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400))

brush = None

game_exit = False

while not game_exit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_exit = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1: # left button pressed
                brush = event.pos
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if event.button == 1: # left button released
                brush = None
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if brush: # left button still pressed
                brush = event.pos

    # clear bufor
    gameDisplay.fill(BLACK)

    # draw brush in bufor
    if brush:
         pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, RED, [brush[0], brush[1], 10, 10])

    # send bufor on the screen                
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thank you. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stable loop that fills, flips and receives events:

```
while True:
       for event in pregame.event.get():
               if event.type == pregame.QUIT:
                        pregame.quit()
         window.fill((0,0,0))
         #####Render here
         pygame.display.flip()
         pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)
```

Hope it helps :D